# Getting error as char cannot be dereferenced in java

Tags: java, char

Getting char cannot be dereferenced error , while writing following code

```
for(int i =1;i<=m;i++){
    for(int j =1;j<=l;j++){
        if(A.charAt(i-1).equals(B.charAt(j-1))){
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j-1] + arr[i-1][j-1];
        }
        else{
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j-1];
        }
    }
}
```

on line if(A.charAt(i-1).equals(B.charAt(j-1)))

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` returns a primitive `char` which does not have methods such as `equals`.

To compare primitives, you can use `==`:

```
if(A.charAt(i-1) == B.charAt(j-1)) {
```